# Given a string variable activity, set the myMood variable to: ’happy’ if the activity is equal to ’coding’ ’bored’ if the activity is anything else

Tags: javascript

Given a string variable activity, set the `myMood` variable to:

’happy’ if the activity is equal to ’coding’

’bored’ if the activity is anything else

I'm really stuck trying to figure out the syntax for this, I tried like 18 times

I tried writing a few conditional statements but non of them were working

Comment: Please attach the examples to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried searching for answers to your question online, or browsing through relevant tutorial articles?

Here are some resources for beginners:

1. [if...else - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
2. [JavaScript Tutorial by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

and here is example code:

```js
let activity = 'coding'; // Example activity
let myMood;

if (activity === 'coding') {
    myMood = 'happy';
} else {
    myMood = 'bored';
}

console.log(myMood); // Outputs: happy
```

This is a basic example of how you can use if...else statements in JavaScript. Check out the aforementioned tutorials for more comprehensive guides.